# Work on kubernetes with two accounts in PowerShell with Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, kubernetes, kubectl, account

I have two separate Azure accounts.

One for each project in which I am involved, these accounts are totally independent, that is, they do not share any type of resource and do not have the same domain. They are from two totally different companies.

I find that both accounts respond to me at the time of login from PowerShell and I can access those resources.

Both work with Kubernetes (kubectl) but only one of the two accounts is shown. Whatever you do always shows the content of co-owners of one and not the other.

I have the Azure CLI (v.2.0.76) and the PS version is (5.1)

someone know how to I can do?

- EDIT with pictures -

Although the account is default, I am not able to access the kubernetes of the same

[PS Default Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tB79.png)

Services from the other account..not the default account

[services from other cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgrKu.png)

Comment: sorry, I dont understand the question. open 2 powershell sessions side by side and work with your accounts independently?

Comment: Not at the same time, the problem I have is that I cannot work with another kubernet account that is not the main one, even if it is not selected.

Comment: why not? I always do that

Comment: I access the account that I am interested in operating, I can see the resources of that account.

But when I do a kubectl it shows me about the other ...

That only happens to me with PowerShell, but I need to work with PS to operate with commands.

Comment: kubectl and az cli\powershell are not connected in any way shape or form, so you can access any kubernetes cluster independently of what azure cli\powershell is connected to

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution.

When we access from PS with Az Login and select the account, it allows us to access all the resources of that account (the one that is predetermined)

What I have done is basically see the

```
kubectl config view
```

This returns the result of all the clusters that it finds with its context. The next thing we have to do is tell kubectl what CONTEXT we want to work with in the following way:

```
kubectl config use-context "CONTEXT NAME"
```

And thats it.